# Redis still has data after Celery run

Tags: redis, celery

I have set up a Celery task that is using RabbitMQ as the broker and Redis as the backend. After running I noticed that my Redis server was still using a lot of memory. Upon inspection I found that there were still keys for each task that was created.

Is there a way to get Celery to clean up these keys only after the response has been received? I know some MessageBrokers use acks, is there an equivalent for a redis backend in Celery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Celery doesn't have acks for its backend, so the best solution for my project was to call forget on my responses after I was done with them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [result_expires](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires). Please note that celery beat should run as well, as written in the documentation:

> A built-in periodic task will delete the results after this time (celery.backend_cleanup), assuming that celery beat is enabled. The task runs daily at 4am.

Comment: Is there a way to do it after a get is called on the async result? My current solution is to use forget after I am done with the result.

Comment: what about setting its value to 1 (second) - it will be deleted right after the task end

Comment: alternatively, don't use backend result if you don't need to.

Comment: I want to use the result and the backend, but I don't want it to stick around after I have gotten it. From my understanding, if I set cleannup to 1 second it could be cleaned up before I get the results from the task. What I was looking for was something similar to an ack where I can say I am done with this result. I guess forget() will work.